# Excercise 2.4 in Jurgen Jost's PDE "Harnack's inequality" for harmonic functions defined on a ball

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $u:B(0,R)\subset \mathbb{R^d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be harmonic and nonnegative. Prove the following version of the Harnack inequality: $$\dfrac{R^{d-2}(R-|x|)}{(R+|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)\leq u(x)\leq \dfrac{R^{d-2}(R+|x|)}{(R-|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)$$.

I know what the usual inequality says and I have the proof of that at hand, however I do not know how to begin. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Do you know the Poisson integral formula in this context? It must follow from that...

Comment: Isn't that exactly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality#The_statement ?

Comment: I dont but, I was just reading from another book, "PDE by L. Evans" and it has the same excercise but gives the following hint "Use Poisson's formula for the ball to prove..." which is (I believe) what you are suggesting. I'll give it a try with said integral and let you know.

Comment: thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2):

For $|y|=R$, we have $R-|x|\le |x-y|\le R+|x|$. Using the Poisson formula, we obtain (when $x\in B(0,R)$) that\begin{align}
u(x) &= \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{d\omega_d R}\int_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{u(y)}{|x-y|^d}d\sigma(y)\\
&\ge \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{(R+|x|)^d d\omega_d R}\int_{\partial B(0,R)}u(y) d\sigma(y)\\
&= \frac{R^{d-2}(R-|x|)}{(R+|x|)^{d-1}}\frac{1}{d\omega_d R^{d-1}}\int_{\partial B(0,R)}u(y) d\sigma(y)\\
&= \frac{R^{d-2}(R-|x|)}{(R+|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)
\end{align}
The last step uses the mean value property of the harmonic function $u$. The other estimation is similar.